# A construction of an uncountable product of independent Bernoulli variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, bernoulli-distribution

I have an intuitive stochastic process as follows, but not sure how to construct it rigorously on some probability space.

Consider the unit interval $[0,1]$, each point $x\in [0,1]$ is associated with an independent Bernoulli($0.5$) random variable. Then each realization can be viewed as a function $f$ from $[0,1]$ to $\{0,1\}$. The level set $\{x: f(x) = 1\}$ is then a random set on $[0,1]$. I want to argue the set is almost surely (Lebesgue)-measurable, and almost-surely has measure $0.5$.

However, the above construction does not seem to be rigorous. Therefore, I want to know if there exists a probability space $\Omega$ that admits the a stochastic process $f(t,\omega) \in \{0,1\}$, such that $1.$ all the finite dimensional distribution is a product of independent Bernoulli. $2.$ For almost every $\omega$, the set $\{x: f(x,\omega) = 1\}$ is measurable, and has probability $0.5$.

It seems the first condition can be guaranteed using the Kolmogorov's extension theorem. But I have not idea how to guarantee the second condition.

Comment: I disagree with your intuition that such a (non-rigorously defined) process should be such that almost surely the set $\{x : f(x) = 1\}$ is Lebesgue-measurable. Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ have to do with the actual interval $[0,1]$ (and the structure of $\mathbb{R}$), whereas for your situation, $[0,1]$ just represents an uncountable set of points that have no relation between one another.

Comment: Such white noise processes are often used in a Gaussian setting. So I would look up how they do this for Gaussian processes. Bernoulli should then be a simple consequence (i.e. Gaussian >0 <0)

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks! I agree that the set ${x: f(x) = 1}$ is not necessarily measurable just from the definition of the process. I am interested in whether it is possible to construct a rigorous process on certain state space such that the random set is almost surely measurable.

Comment: @mathworker21 I agree with your intuition, see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is impossible. Let $\mu$ denote Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. If  $A(\omega)=\{x: f(x,\omega) = 1\}$
is measurable then $\mu\bigl(A(\omega) \cap [A(\omega)+t]\bigr) \to \mu(A)=1/2$ as $t \to 0$.
But $$E\Bigl(\mu\bigl(A(\omega) \cap [A(\omega)+t]\bigr)\Bigr)
$$ $$=\int_\Omega \int_0^1 f(x,\omega) f(x-t,\omega) \,dx \,dP
$$ $$=
\int_0^1 \int_\Omega  f(x,\omega) f(x-t,\omega) \,dP \, dx=1/4\,,$$
and this is a contradiction in view of Lebesgue's bounded convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know how to accept an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers